# How to find out my own user id for usage on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support

In order to run queries on data.stackexchange.com one often needs to enter a user id (e.g. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag). I'm having trouble to figure out what to enter.

When I log into data.stackexchange.com, I have to use OpenID where I selected SE's OpenID. I'm logged in as `jon.doe18095` which I don't understand because it has nothing to do with my username. Entering `jon.doe18095` for the query referced above fails with error `The multi-part identifier "jon.doe18095" could not be bound.`. Entering `18095` reveals result which are not at all related to any of my SE account (exclusively displays tags which I never have posted something to and none of those I've been involved with).

On my profile site there's no such thing as a user id and I don't seem to find another place where to find it.

Comment: data.stackexchange.com uses a completely separate user system than the other stack exchange sites. For your query you'll want to enter the user ID you have on the site that you're running the query on.

Comment: But I don't know that ID...

Comment: It's in the URL of your profile. For example, on Ask Ubuntu you are user `173287`.

Comment: @KarlRichter: finally I understand as well. See answer below.  Sorry for the confusion, but I'm confused and confusing all the time!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the top of this page next to your avatar.

Then click on "network profile", then depending on which site you're trying to get data on, choose that site (E.g. meta.stackechange) and only then will you see on the right side on the top in the search field `user:255844` (this is for [Karl Richter](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/173287/karl-richter) only and for the meta.stackexchange.com site only, another user will see a different number for the site he/she/it chooses)

255844 is your user id for that particular site...

Comment: Follow up: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13774/reveal-user-id-in-visible-text-in-user-profile