# Reveal user id in visible text in user profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

Currently the user id can be revealed by copying the user profile link or write it digit by digit from the link popup tooltip (in case you use GUI browser). That's quite compilated and non-transperant. Any change to get the id displayed as copyable text on the user profile site?

Example use cases include:

- usage on [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: What link popup? The user id is right there in the user page URL. What more do you need?

Comment: @terdon What I requested in the question...

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand what you're asking for. The user ID is rarely useful but for those times when it is needed, all you need to do is go to the user in question's user page and copy the id from the URL:

[image: animated gif showing the selection of the user id]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wrote in the question... In case you know that the user id is in the URL which acutally a handful of users might know. But the overhead to add a label in the form of `User id: <user id>` is too trivial and useful to not propose it.

Comment: @KarlRichter there are very few cases where the user ID is needed.  In fact,  I can't think of any. The chat user ID is sometimes useful for searching chat room transcripts, but when would you need the site user ID? Why clutter up the profile page? Am I missing something? When would you want the user ID?